# Reading many images into memory at once in python openCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm working on an openCV interface where I'm displaying a bunch of sequential images (a video really, but I'm using images). I'd like to be able to "scroll" really quickly through the images by holding down a key. My current implementation is pretty naive, it loops through all the images and does this:

```
frame = cv2.imread(img_file, 1)
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

So there is the IO latency of reading from disk everytime, which I think is what makes it painfully slow. Is there any nice way from the python API to load all the images in memory, or at least batch in memory with something like `imread`, so I can have them available while flipping through? Or open to any suggestions on how to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add each frame to a list, access by a list index

```
frames=[]
files = [...some list of files..]
for img_file in files:
    frame = cv2.imread(img_file, 1)
    frames.append[frame]

# and then later
for frame in frames:
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)


# or by individual frame
     cv2.imshow('frame', frames[123])
```